# user Name must contain following criteria

Tags: javascript, java, regex

userName must contain following criteria

for Username

UserName have a minimum of 8 and a maximum of 16 alphanumeric characters and also meet at least below parameters.
1)One - lowercase, 
2)One - uppercase, 
3)One - special Character, 
4)One -  number
5)Period, Hyphen and 
6)Sub-script any one of the special characters is mandatory to complete a username.

for Password

1)The user must have a minimum of 8 and a maximum of 12 characters,
2) plus it must be alphanumeric.
3)Point, Script, and Sub-script any one of the special characters is mandatory to complete a Password.

in that case, what are the characters in Script, and Sub-script?

I tried to like this

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-.^]).{8,16}.
```

Is it valid Regular expression? could you please help me.

I think my regular expression does not contain any Sub-script character.

In the stack, overflow Search results not contain any Sub-script character.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for your replay i am using javascript